# If a graph contains $3$ blocks and $k$ cut vertices, what are the possible values of $k$?

Tags: graph-theory

Since blocks can intersect in at most one articulation point, There are from 0 to 3 cut vertices.

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure if I need to expand on this or if it is enough of an explanation.

Comment: Why don't you show us the examples you found with zero, one, two, and three cut vertices?

Answer (score 1):

You need to show one more thing that $k \neq 3$. That is $k=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer is k=1,2
k cant be 0 otherwise the whole graph will become a block.and also k can't be 3 because it would create a circle and the graph will become non-separable or it would create a forth block.
i also found this pdf but there was no explanation there:
[connectivity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwivkPHHl7P0AhW0gv0HHbe7CrkQFnoECAMQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcslabcms.nju.edu.cn%2Fproblem_solving%2Fimages%2F6%2F64%2F2019-3-10-connectivity.pdf&usg=AOvVaw243YxJVk_tPapqf1ezVlIp)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).